# flex col inside flex row inside.. 's taller than its container

Tags: css, google-chrome, flexbox

I think I just encountered a bug in **chrome**. By embedding flex columns inside flex rows (or the opposite) I end up with wrong boxes height that make them go out of their parent.

I tried to reproduce that here and it (the failure) "*worked*" http://jsfiddle.net/b8QvP/1/

html:

```
<div class="root">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                We Are
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                Too Tall
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">            
            ( only when I'm here )
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.row, .col {
    height: 80%;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 1em;
    display: flex;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: cursive;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.root { height: 400px; width: 600px; }
.row { flex-direction: row; }
.col { flex-direction: column; }

div > div  { background-color: #CCC; }
div > div > div { background-color: #AAA; }
div > div > div > div { background-color: #888; }
```

result:

[image: result]

however, I have no problem with firefox.

Have I missed something ? If not, is there any workaround (apart from avoiding flex)? and then how and where could I check if it is already reported / known  ?

Comment: `display:flex` as direct child of `display:flex` as direct child of `display:flex`? Not sure if good approach.

Comment: why ? Shouldn't it be like using `display:block` inside `display:block `or anything else ?

Comment: My thinking was that a Flexbox container cannot be a Flexbox item (and vice versa), but it [seems to work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/84tXY/).